# Kivy on Android, JVM exception occurred: Attempt to invoke virtual method ... on a null object reference

Tags: java, python, android, kivy, uri

We're trying to access the Android camera in the Kivy app we're building. We first opted to use `plyer` but we were getting a `ClipData.Item.getUri()` error. We ended up trying to follow the details described here: https://github.com/kivy/plyer/issues/500#issuecomment-565532048

Now there seems to be a problem in getting the URI for a file.

We have added this in `AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml`:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
    ...

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="org.our.appnamehere"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

and this in the `file_paths.xml` as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path  name="external_files"  path="Android/data/org.our.appnamehere/files/Pictures"  />
</paths>
```

We've tried changing the `android:authorities` line into `org.our.appnamehere.provider` and `org.our.appnamehere.fileprovider`as well as changing the corresponding `getUriForFile` in the given file from the link above

```
...

photo_file = self._create_image_file()

if photo_file is not None:
    photo_uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    self.currentActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                    self.currentActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                    photo_file
                )

...
```

into either `self.currentActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + '.provider'` or `self.currentActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + '.fileprovider'`.

The app seems to be successful in creating the file that `photo_file` links to, as we can access them under `Android/data/org.our.appnamehere/files/Pictures`. We always get the following error, presumably from the `photo_uri` line:

```
JavaException("JVM Exception occurred: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference")
```

The smartphone on which we are running the compiled app is on Android Pie, Version 9.

Nearly all solutions to this error just looks like the ones we have added into the manifest and the file_paths.xml. In addition to the several variations of `android:authorities`, we also tried the following lines from this link: https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage/issues/103#issuecomment-304304045

```
        <provider
            ...
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                ...
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>
```

They do not really work and we still can't access the camera. We might just be missing something obvious...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I opened the AndroidManifest.xml inside the .apk and it seems the provider tags are not there at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were in fact just missing something obvious.

Running

```
buildozer android clean
```

and rebuilding the .apk did the trick. The hint was that the `<provider>` tags are not included in the .apk's manifest despite being in the template.

We can now take pictures and save files with the camera.

What happens now is that the app does not seem to resume by itself after taking a capture, but that is a separate issue altogether.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. Can you please share the camera.py file you made?  Thank a lot

Comment: @kpk Hi, I just saw your comment today. Try this: https://pastebin.com/QPYc94Hz

Comment: Hi. I finally did it, creating a FileManager and editing the AndroidManifest file. I have clear  instructions from a user at kivy-users@googlegroups.com. it's similar to your code, if you are interesting in, I will upload it here. Now I am facing problems to open the stored image by the default android app. Do you have anything about this ?